# How can I determine at run-time whether a form is an MDI form?

Tags: vb6

VB6 has two form objects, the SDI and MDI.  They have common properties, but each of a few properties that the other does not have.  I created a function to manage the size of any form in the project that uses .BorderStyle to change only those forms that are sizable.  When the MDI is evaluated and executes the .BorderStyle property, it errors out.  How do I programmatically determine if a VB6 form is an MDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If TypeOf f Is MDIForm Then
   ...
End If
```

Comment: I looked high and low on the net for code like that; just couldn't find anything that was close.  Thank you very much.